# Fastest Video Format to decode on Android 3.0+ Tablet

Tags: android, video

Hi I'm building an application for Android tablets which basically is a sequence of pages (think of it as a book), but on each of this pages I have a looping video on the background.

The problem I'm having right now is that when you fling to change pages the transitions are very slow and not very smooth.

Since the heaviest part of my pages are the background videos I was wondering if there is a video format that is very fast to decode and possibly optimized for Android, even if it has a larger filesize.

Right know my videos have these characteristics (output from ffprobe):

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'tab0.mp4':
Metadata:
major_brand     : mp42
minor_version   : 1
compatible_brands: mp42mp41
creation_time   : 2011-06-28 16:16:54
Duration: 00:00:05.44, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 5994 kb/s
Stream #0.0(eng): Video: mpeg4, yuv420p, 800x1234 [PAR 1:1 DAR 400:617], 5992 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 1k tbc
Metadata:
  creation_time   : 2011-06-28 16:16:54
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> bitrate: 5994 kb/s

I imagine that's your main problem

Use video content with a much lower bit rate like 750kb/s